# R: Splitting df, then summarize with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a large df that that I would like to summarize with dplyr commands. However, I don't want a summary across the entire df, because it contains snapshots of my data at different points in time. So what I am trying to do is first split the data by a date column, and then do my summarizing within each subset. I am not sure how to combine the sapply (or something similar) command with the regular chaining of dplyr.

Below is a sample dataset. The end goal with this data would be to get sums and percentages of the amount by expiration year for each date. In other words, I would have three summary tables/dfs resulting from the analysis: one for each of the three dates in the first column.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16596, 16596, 16596, 16266, 
16266, 16266, 15706, 15706, 15706), class = "Date"), amount = c(1, 
5, 10, 11, 20, 3, 4, 6, 2), expirationyear = c(2020, 2030, 2020, 
2022, 2021, 2023, 2021, 2020, 2021)), .Names = c("Date", "amount", 
"expirationyear"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output (as requested):

> table 1: 2015-06-10
>
> 1. 2020: 11; 11/16
> 2. 2030: 5; 5/16
>
> table 2: 2014-07-15
>
> 1. 2020: 10; 10/41
> 2. 2021: 20; 20/41
> 3. 2022: 11; 11/41
>
> table 3: 2013-01-01
>
> 1. 2020: 6; 6/12
> 2. 2021: 6; 6/12

I assume this would be a list of tables, but since I am not sure how to implement, I may be wrong.

Comment: Added above in crude way

Comment: `lapply(split(DF, DF$Date), function(dd) dd %>% group_by(expirationyear) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(amount)) %>% mutate(Percent = Sum/sum(Sum)*100))`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yeah, that looks like a good way. Within the hadleyverse (with magrittr), one could also write the function like `. %>% ...` instead of `function(dd) dd %>% ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to split the data into a list and use `lapply`, you could do it like so:

```
lapply(split(DF, DF$Date), function(dd) {
  dd %>% 
    group_by(expirationyear) %>% 
    summarise(Sum = sum(amount)) %>% 
    mutate(Percent = Sum/sum(Sum)*100)
  })
```

The other (and imo simpler) option is to simply group by Date and expirationyear:

```
DF %>% 
    group_by(Date, expirationyear) %>% 
    summarise(Sum = sum(amount)) %>% 
    mutate(Percent = Sum/sum(Sum)*100)
```

Comment: That is great, thank you! Completely agree that the 2nd one is simpler - completely avoid need to split. Thanks again.